# MySQL Query (Update each row depending on a join)

Tags: mysql

I've got a database with just over 10 million rows. Here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `map` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `good` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `terrian_type` int(11) NOT NULL,

   ... 6 more int columns

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `x` (`x`),
  KEY `y` (`y`),
  KEY `terrian_type` (`terrian_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This contains a world map, where (x,y) is defined as the co-ordinates of a specific square. Each square, has a terrain type.

What I want to do, is update each square, with a boolean ("good"). A square is classified as "good" if the 8 surrounding squares all share the same terrain_type (the square in question does not matter).

Here is my query to tell if 1 specific square/row is good (x,y) = (5,5):

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(in1.terrian_type),
    in1.terrian_type 
FROM `worldmap` w1
INNER JOIN `worldmap` in1
  ON in1.x >= w1.x-1
  AND in1.x <= w1.x+1
  AND in1.y >= w1.y-1
  AND in1.y <= w1.y+1
  AND IF(in1.y = w1.y, IF(in1.x = w1.x, 0, 1), 1) = 1
WHERE w1.x = '5'
AND w1.y = '5'
GROUP BY in1.terrian_type
```

If more than 1 row returned, it is not "good".

Hoping someone could help with determining if each square is good (each of the 10 million). Looping through each one using query above is going to take far too long! This only needs to be done once a month.

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

The following looks ugly and is probably not too efficient (unless you have indexes on x and y) but I think this should work:

```
SELECT maptext.x, maptest.y, IF(maptext.terrian_type = x1y.terrian_type AND maptext.terrian_type = x1y1.terrian_type AND maptext.terrian_type = xy1.terrian_type AND maptext.terrian_type = x_1y1.terrian_type AND maptext.terrian_type = x_1y.terrian_type AND maptext.terrian_type = x_1y_1.terrian_type AND maptext.terrian_type = xy_1.terrian_type AND maptext.terrian_type = x1y_1.terrian_type, 'GOOD','BAD')
    FROM worldmap maptest
    INNER JOIN worldmap x1y
    on maptest.x = x1y.x + 1 and maptest.y = x1y.y
    INNER JOIN worldmap x1y1
    on maptest.x = x1y1.x + 1 and maptest.y = x1y1.y + 1
    INNER JOIN worldmap xy1
    on maptest.x = xy1.x and maptest.y = xy1.y + 1
    INNER JOIN worldmap x_1y1
    on maptest.x = x_1y1.x - 1 and maptest.y = x_1y1.y + 1
    INNER JOIN worldmap x_1y
    on maptest.x = x_1y.x - 1 and maptest.y = x_1y.y 
    INNER JOIN worldmap x_1y_1
    on maptest.x = x_1y_1.x - 1 and maptest.y = x_1y_1.y - 1
    INNER JOIN worldmap xy_1
    on maptest.x = xy_1.x and maptest.y = xy_1.y - 1
    INNER JOIN worldmap x1y_1
    on maptest.x = x1y_1.x + 1 and maptest.y = x1y_1.y - 1
```

Comment: This one query took about 5.4s on average (5.4s x 8m = a lot). Thanks though!